# QFIleDialog only filters one time

Tags: qt

I have a QfileDialog that it is opened when I push in a button. This button actives a signal and call a Slot with this code:

```
QString s =  QFileDialog::getOpenFileName ( 

                this,  
                "Open a Map" ,  
                lastPath,  
                "Maps (*.png *.bmp);;Info (*.xml)" 
                );
```

I don't understand why, but the first time I push the button, the Qfiledialog filters rightly. But the following times don't work fine. It filters nothing.

Ok, I have tried another way:

```
   QFileDialog dialog(this);
   dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
   dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png)"));
   dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);

  QStringList fileNames;
  if (dialog.exec())
  fileNames = dialog.selectedFiles();
```

If I use this method, the window is not a ubuntu window, it is a Qdialog window, I suppose. But works fine anytime.

Comment: What operating system do you have? Your example works with WinXP and Qt 4.6.2. (and you could fix your code example by indenting it by 4 spaces)

Comment: Try `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, ...);` variant ...

Comment: I use ubuntu, Qt 4.6.2 and qtcreator 2.0 in develop. Thanks mosg but it doesn't work. I keep to search.

Comment: Are you deleting `this` object during execution of this dialog? Documentation warns about this.

Comment: Have you debugged that there is no memory corruption involved? check that the filter string is correct the second time.

Comment: Sorry Justanothercoder, I leave this problem as "It almost works, next problem" XD. I am not actually working in Qt now. Thanks a lot